# radio buttons in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android

i have a basic information form with textfield, radiofield, and numberfield

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="Your Information"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

</TableRow>
<View 
        android:background="@drawable/barbell"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"/>


<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nickname: " 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:textColor="#333333"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/infoname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="3 to 10 characters" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender: " 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:textColor="#333333"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/inforadioGender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/inforadioM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"/>
        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/inforadioF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Female" />
    </RadioGroup>


</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Age: " 
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="#333333"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/infoage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" 
        android:hint="5 to 99" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</TableRow>
```

i used sharedpreference and its editor for passing the string and number..
but i badly need a tutorial or for beginner in the radio button?
is it possible to do without creating preferences.xml(which i don't want to mess around yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadioGroup has the methods `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` and `check(int id)`. So, if you want to save the views state, you could simply store the id of the selected radio button, which is an int and if you want to load your view again, you could call the check method and pass in the saved int to select the radio button again.

Comment: thanks, it worked but resulted in some long integer :(, any solution to this?

Comment: That's ok. It's the id, which was assigned to the radio button by the android SDK. Print out the value of `R.id.inforadioM` and `R.id.inforadioF`. One of them should be equal to the value you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android's default sqlite database to store the data.

To get you started with radio buttons, this is a good reference from android

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/RadioGroup1.html

Comment: in these demo, don't they have xml files with it?